# Bootstrap customize download Style missing on the grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I just want to include the only the grid system from bootstrap into my project for that I have downloaded bootstrap grid from [this link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/). But some styles are missing on that file.

Normal bootstrap.css

```
    .row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Style from Customized bootstrap.css

```
    .row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

As you can see properties which are related to `flex` is missing on the custom downloaded bootstrap css but its still on the normal bootstrap.

Comment: `display: flex`  css is in `bootstrap4` , and you are using `bootstrap3`...  so use `bootstrap4` then you can see  `display: flex`   css

Comment: Just changed to version 4 but the option for the customization is missing.

Comment: which customization ?????????

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the **Bootstrap 4 grid only**, use the **bootstrap-grid.css** from here:

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/contents/#css-files

This includes the grid, flexbox and display utilities, but *not* all the element styles and utilities like the borders, spacing, etc..

---

There is no longer an *official* Bootstrap customization tool like there was for [3.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/). For 4.x, you have to [use your own tooling](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/build-tools/), or a unofficial customizer such as [Themestr.app](https://themestr.app/customize) that will let you change any of the over 500 SASS vars (caveat: I built this tool).